# How to assign select permission for all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, permissions

I want to assign select permission to a user, for all tables, and I need this permission work for every table which will be added to database.

I can assign select permission to my user (data_reader) for all tables which are currently in database, by executing my code result:

```
select 'grant select on object::'+s.name+'.'+t.name+' to data_reader'
from sys.schemas s
inner join sys.tables t on s.schema_id=t.schema_id
```

my problem is, if any table added to database I have to execute grant select on that table for data_reader, so it may be forgotten.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find a way to grant select to all tables in all schemas to my user, forever.

Comment: When you say data_reader, do you mean db_datareader? Someone must have messed with the default settings for it in your db because that role can read from all tables (doesn't need specific per table permission) by default - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Read this, and examine whether someone has not issued a GRANT for all tables to the role you're talking about (when you say data_reader) - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/

Comment: No data_reader is a database user which I made it. I want to assign select all tables and also future tables to data_reader user, which is a database user which I created it.

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry I forgot to mentioned you.Thanks for link too ;)

Comment: @CaiusJard I read the link. I think best option is to assign db_datareader to my user.
I wanted to assign grant select directly to my user, but I searched a lot, I think there is not any way
Thanks for mentioning db_datareader, it helped me a lot. thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

If all your tables are in the dbo schema then this would be :

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO specialrole
```

and try it :

```
GRANT {  { schemaPrivileges        | SELECT [ PRIVILEGES ] } ON { SCHEMA <schema_name> | ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE <db_name> }
   | { schemaObjectPrivileges  | SELECT [ PRIVILEGES ] } ON FUTURE <object_type>S IN SCHEMA <schema_name> }
TO [ ROLE ] <role_name> [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Comment: Is there any way to grant select to a user for database? I have 20 schema on my database and it may be add up more.
Is there any way or I should grant select to any schema after it created?
thanks

Comment: A schema is a database-level securable contained by the database that is its parent in the permissions hierarchy. In my humble opinion, you should grant select to any schema after it created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you are interested read comments under my question. after CaiusJard and your response I searched a bit more and I think I have to do your way to assign select directly to my user or assign db_datareader role to my user.
Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to give the rights db_datareader in the mapping to the desired database:

```
USE [DBName]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [user_name]
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

I check this problem on SQL Server 2017

I create a login with Stack Name and map to Data Base User without any permission

Then i grant Select permission to user

```
grant select to Stack;
```